# Undefined Offset 1 error

Tags: php, laravel

```
$div_odds = $div - > getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach($div_odds as $od) {
    $class_od = $od - > getAttribute('class');
    if ($class_od == 'CSegno') {
      $expolde = preg_split('/\n|\r\n?/', $div - > textContent);
      $part - > type = explode('Segno:', $expolde[3])[1];
      $part - > cote = str_replace(',', '.', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $expolde[2]));
    }
```

It shows below error message:

> 'Undefined Offset 1'

Comment: by inspecting the response , i discover it can you help me

Comment: You are probably making reference to an array index which doesn't exist!

Comment: Would assume error is in `$part->type = explode('Segno:',$expolde[3])[1];`, so check that your explode works before assuming it returns an array.

Comment: Post the content of `dd(explode('Segno:',$expolde[3]));` here. Call this function after `preg_split`.

Comment: https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/534604Capture.jpg

Comment: array:1 [
  0 => "                                                3,98"
]

Comment: this when dd($explode);
array:9 [
  0 => ""
  1 => "                                            "
  2 => "                                            "
  3 => "                                                3,98"
  4 => "                                            "
  5 => "                                            "
  6 => "                                                Segno:X2DC"
  7 => "                                            "
  8 => "                                        "
]

Comment: can you show content of print_r($expolde[3])

Comment: what is the output/$part->type value you are expecting?

Comment: this what i want to expect https://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/924540Capture.jpg
also segno is reference type enum in database

Comment: Why are you trying to access  `$expolde[3][1]`? It doesnt exist. `$res = trim($explode[3])`